# UITableViewCell title positioning

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am creating an app with UITableViewCells that expand when selected. However, when the cell expands, the title (and subtitle) are moving downwards to stay centered vertically in the cell. I'd like them to stay where they were originally but can't figure out how to do it.

I have tried setting the frame manually with `cell.textLabel?.frame = myRect`, but this does nothing. I am unable to find any constraints, as `print(cell.textLabel?.constraints)` returns `optional([])`.

Here are my [normal cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxPhz.png) and my [expanded cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZAon.png).

My code for creating the cells:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")
    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .value1, reuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")
    }
    cell!.textLabel?.text = content[indexPath.row]
    cell!.clipsToBounds = true
    cell!.selectionStyle = .none
    cell!.detailTextLabel?.text = detailContent[indexPath.row]
    return cell!
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a standardized cell, the title and detail are fixed, i think  you need make a custom cell for your project

Look this project I make a simple test with customized cell
https://github.com/TexugoProgramador/Teste-Celula-Customizada

Comment: Thank you, great example. How would you go about doing it without the storyboard, all programmaticaly?

Comment: I never make a custom cell using only code, why you can use a storyboard?

Comment: Found out by myself :) I think the main reason why you would create it in code is for the flexibility, but that’s just the way I’m used to doing it